# Calculation of the resistors values in a voltage divider

Tags: resistors, 5v, 3.3v, calculation

I'm working on a circuit where a 3.3v flash memory, which comunicate with SPI protocol, has to be interfaced to an 8-bit PIC microcontroller working at 5v. For the MISO signal there should not be any problem, but for MOSI, SCK and CS there are. So the solution i came across is a voltage divider. I've done this calculations but don't know if they are ok.
_ First of all, i've calculated r1 in this way:
(5-3.3)/0.001=1700 ohm
_ Then i've resolved the equation
Vout = Vin * (r2 / (r1+r2))
3.3 = 5 * (r2/(1700+r2))
...resolving the equation in order to find r2...

r2=3300 ohm.
Is that correct? i have not any tester and i have just one flash memory. i don't want to fry it...
Is the method i've used proper (first determinate r1 with the current and then find r2)?
Thank you very very much.
Greetings from Italy.

Comment: Who knows what R1 is and what R2 is - you didn't show a circuit. This may seem trivial but it isn't. You should also link the data sheet for the flash memory and state what speed you hope to achieve.

Comment: Which PIC model? Have you checked 3.3V is above logic 1 threshold? At what speeds you plan to communicate? Any capacitance (stray, pin) after the divider will round down the edges, and there is a limit how round edges the SPI flash works with. Basically, resistor divider can be used for low speed stuff, but it may have issues with high speed stuff.

Comment: The microcontroller is a PIC18F46Q10.

Comment: The flash is the SST25VF080B, the clock of sck is at 2 Mhz

Comment: For the circuit take the CS line like an example:                                                                               from the pin of the microcontroller, first there is R1, after that there is:                                           _R2 which goes to 0v                                                                                                     
_and the CS of the flash

Comment: @Justme, yes, i've checked that for the microcontroller Vih should be at least 2v. (pag 719 )

Comment: I would suggest using a voltage translator chip such as SN74LVC1T45.

Comment: Answer the following question: Consider series connected resistor of 1700 and 3300 ohms. With the 1700 ohm resistor connected to 5V and the 3300 ohm resistor connected to ground, what is the voltage at the junction of the two resistors? Yes, I'm asking the same question that you are, but really I'm asking you if you can check your own answer by working the problem backwards.

Comment: Potential difference referred to 0v with theoretical no load (CMOS flash input): Vr2 = r2(V / (r1+r2)) --> Vr2=3300(5/(1700+3300)) Vr2=3.3V and vr1=1.7V.  But, yesterday i have calculated r1=876 and r2=1700 and... the results are the same: Vr2 =1700(5/(876+1700)) Vr2=3.3.

Comment: How can it be? Anyway, assuming that i'm referring to 0v, I don't understand if i should calculate the desired voltage drop first on r1 or first on r2 (r2 connected to 0v and r1 to positive voltage power supply).  Or perhaps ,in this case that the resistors are just two, it doesn't make any difference which one i do calculate first.

Comment: If you've done it correctly, you'll get the same answer both ways.

Comment: @morov Where is the datasheet for the flash memory? Usually, one can find the absolute maximum protection diode current allowed, given that much. That will help a lot in determining the required \$R_\text{TH}\$ of the divider. (You already know that \$V_\text{TH}=3.3\:\text{V}\$.) Given those two values, it's just:$$\begin{align*}R_1&=R_\text{TH} \cdot \frac{\left(V_\text{CC}=5\:\text{V}\right)}{\left(V_\text{TH}=3.3\:\text{V}\right)}\\\\R_2&=R_\text{TH} \cdot \frac{\left(V_\text{CC}=5\:\text{V}\right)}{\left(V_\text{CC}=5\:\text{V}\right)-\left(V_\text{TH}=3.3\:\text{V}\right)}\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Dave Tweed and what did I do wrong in the calculation above?

Comment: And this is the datasheet of the flash. https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/268/20005045D-1826881.pdf